# Any way to remove extra information when printing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, printing

I currently use two browsers: chrome and firefox.
On windows, for example, firefox adds the following to each page when printing web pages:

```
title in top left
url in the top right
page number on bottom left
time/date on the bottom right
```

Is there any way to get rid of that?

Furthermore, in linux, firefox doesn't print at all. It generates a pdf. Is this just that firefox doesn't properly support linux, or is there some way to configure it?

Comment: Did you check the FF settings (it's probably the same for Chrome too...). Under print "options" deselect "Print headers and footers".

Comment: did you try (at)media print {
  (at)page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}

Comment: these are the limits of what you can do with the page at-rule for printed media formating. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Comment: If that does not work try deleting this question and ask a question about how to use (at)page ... the framing of the question looks like a superuser.stackexchange.com question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printer headline and footline are added in the printing application thus can be different per print driver/ printing user. Unrelated to any browser html.

For Chrome/Foxit/Skia --headless PDF printer they can be switched off.

Most Firefox user settings will be remembered in each profile so save a print once it should generally use the same next time. Here I set no margins and blank heading/footing data plus show background in a Landscape. The one thing you cannot change is Paper Format so here it is my default of A5.

[image]

[image]

NOTE Pdf printing does not have to include headers, this Firefox PDF Page print has no means to add them. Since Browser Print is always controlled by browser user, there are 8 billion ways and counting.

[image]